# Interpreting dividends data from Yahoo Finance

Tags: dividends, yahoofinance

I'm creating a very simple program that calculates the money generated from SPY dividends in a particular period of time.

I was able to find the historical data in Yahoo Finance (https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/SPY/history?period1=728265600&period2=1697932800&interval=capitalGain%7Cdiv%7Csplit&filter=div&frequency=1d&includeAdjustedClose=true), but **its not clear to me what the dividend number means exactly**.

Is that number dollars per share? Or is it a percentage from the value of each share? *I think its dollars per share*, but I wanted to confirm before writing a program that did the wrong calculation.

Comment: Yes these are the quarterly dividends expressed in Dollars per share. You can find higher precision (more digits) in some other web site such as https://app.tiingo.com/spy/dividends and https://www.nasdaq.com/market-activity/etf/spy/dividend-history